# Why is PHP class not found in a script when it works fine in another?

Tags: php

I have two scripts. Both scripts are located in the same folder on the same server.

Script 1:

```
<?php

$text = "Is this not working? Why, yes it is.";

$locale = 'en_US';

$i = IntlBreakIterator::createSentenceInstance($locale);
$i->setText($text);

foreach($i->getPartsIterator() as $sentence) {
    echo $sentence . PHP_EOL . '----- next -----' .  PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Script 2:

```
... bunch of other code ...

$doc = file_get_contents("file.txt");

$locale = 'en_US';

$i = IntlBreakIterator::createSentenceInstance($locale);
$i->setText($doc);

foreach($i->getPartsIterator() as $sentence) {
    echo $sentence . PHP_EOL . '----- next -----' .  PHP_EOL;
}

... bunch of other code ...
```

Script 1 executes as expected, with the desired output and no errors. Script 2 does not execute and PHP keeps throwing the error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'IntlBreakIterator' not found`

What is going on here?

Comment: try `\IntlBreakIterator` in your second code

Comment: Do both/either have `include` or `use` statements in them?

Comment: Where did you declare your `IntlBreakIterator` class?

Comment: @Isitar Doesn't work.

Comment: @Patrick Q The second only has a require statement, but its to a simple PHP script that loads a database connection. The first has neither.

Comment: @Alex No where in either of them. It works without declaring in the first script, because I'm assuming it is part of PHP base? See http://php.net/manual/en/class.intlbreakiterator.php

Comment: @user4951834 Do either have a `namespace` declaration?

Comment: @PatrickQ No. The first script is literally as shown. The second has a bunch of other code, but nothing that would mess with a native PHP class.

Comment: don't you have `namespace` keyword somewhere in your `... bunch of other code ...`?

Comment: @Alex No, I don't.

Comment: Would it make a difference with how I'm executing the two scripts? The first one I'm executing directly myself through command line. The second I'm executing through the PHP exec() command.

Comment: The only difference you can get that if one script is running under `php-cli` and another one with `php-fpm` for example and they have different config. So add command `die(phpinfo());` in both of them and check for `intl` package in both